# ArguementNullException in Create() View of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to build a `Create()` View to add new People but I am getting an `ArgumentNullException` when it gets to the `DropDownListFor` option.

My **Roles** tables has three roles *Actor*, *Director*, and *Producer* (value 1,2,3 respectively for their Key ID) and I want them to populate this dropdownbox on `Create()`.

My friend got this to work for an `Edit()` function to update my database of People and now I am trying to do it for `Create()`. I originally auto-generated the default **Methods** and **Views** (*create, edit, details, delete, index*) in Visual Studio, but I have been going through and gutting them out to fit in my custom information/queries. 
Everything works now except for my `Create()` method.

the exact error is

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Below is some code snippets for the `create.cshtml` View, the `Create()` Controller methods, and my `EmployeeDetailModel` Viewmodel.

**Create()**

```
// GET: /Movies/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var model = new EmployeeDetailModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

**Create(EmployeeDetailModel model)**

*Not sure if this code will work yet as my app has not yet passed the Create View due to the error, but I am putting it here for reference*

```
// POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeDetailModel model)
{
   MovieEmployee newMovieEmployee = new MovieEmployee();
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      newMovieEmployee.roleID = model.NewRoleId;
      newMovieEmployee.employeeID = model.Employee.ID;
      newMovieEmployee.movieID = model.MovieEmployee.movieID;
      Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
      newEmployee.Birthday = model.Employee.Birthday;
      newEmployee.Name = model.Employee.Name;

      db.MovieEmployees.Add(newMovieEmployee);
      db.Employees.Add(newEmployee);

      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("EmployeeInformation");
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

**Create.cshtml** - This is where the error occurs, at the `@Html.DropDownListFor...`

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.EmployeeDetailModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Movie</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieEmployee.roleID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieEmployee.movieID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MovieEmployee.employeeID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.NewRoleId, Model.Roles.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Selected = (x.ID == Model.MovieEmployee.roleID), Text = x.RoleType, Value = x.ID.ToString() }))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewRoleId)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Birthday, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.Birthday)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Birthday)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "EmployeeInformation")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**EmployeeDetailModel**

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
public class EmployeeDetailModel
    {
        public WebApplication2.Entities.Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public WebApplication2.Entities.MovieEmployee MovieEmployee { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public int NewRoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

I am still in the early learning stage of MVC, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when you create the empty `EmployeeDetailModel`, is the constructor doing anything clever? If not, then code like `Model.Roles.Select` and `Model.MovieEmployee.roleID` in your view will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
Model.Roles.Select
```

In the model itself `Roles` is not initialized to anything, and therefore is of course null. When it is passed to the extension method `Select` this throws an error.

You need to initialize this collection, either in constructor of the model class, or in the action before you call `return View(model);`. So:

```
public class EmployeeDetailModel
{
    public WebApplication2.Entities.Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public WebApplication2.Entities.MovieEmployee MovieEmployee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public int NewRoleId { get; set; }

    public EmployeeDetailModel()
    {
        Roles = new List<WebApplication2.Entities.Role>();
    }
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new EmployeeDetailModel();
    model.Roles = new List<WebApplication2.Entities.Role>();
    return View(model);
}
```